Issues with connecting to Kafka topic as a Consumer
I'm new to Kafka and am trying to get a simple consumer working for my application. I have tried getting python-kafka and confluent-kafka to work.
My consumer config properties are the following:
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': <bootstrap server>,
        'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
        'sasl.mechanism': 'PLAIN',
        'group.id': 'mygroup',
        'sasl.username': <USERNAME>,
        'sasl.password': <PASSWORD>}

While I am able to connect to the server using the Kafka CLI, I am unable to get any messages using either python-kafka or confluent-kafka.
In confluent-kafka, I get a connection timed out error on repeat.
%4|1727131307.906|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:<bootstrap_server>/bootstrap]: <bootstrap_server>/bootstrap: Connection setup timed out in state CONNECT (after 30329ms in state CONNECT)

In python-kafka, I get one of two issues: either no response from the consumer at all (infinitely hangs), or a "No Brokers Available" error.
I was able to previously connect to this groups Kafka topic using the config properties above. However, their bootstrap servers changed and after changing the bootstrap servers I cannot connect. I'm being told the issue is on my end with my config, since I can connect using the CLI with my provided credentials.
I've tried changing my consumer config properties security protocol, setting the auto.offset.reset property, and connecting to the fallback bootstrap servers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If the bootstrap servers changed, then sounds like the advertised.listeners on the cluster are misconfigured and you'll need to ask the server admins for assistance. Otherwise, you'll need to share your non-Python CLI configs that are working. Can you also reproduce with kcat since that would share the same config as the Confluent Python client?

@OneCricketeer Thank you for the response. I'll try reaching out to the server admins, have had some trouble getting in touch with them though. I tried installing kcat, and running with the same config. I got the following error:
SSL handshake failed: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed: broker certificate could not be verified, verify that ssl.ca.location is correctly configured or root CA certificates are installed (brew install openssl)
When you say I'll need to share my CLI configs that are working, can you elaborate on what you mean?

What CLI tool is working? If you're trying to connect with SASL_SSL, you'll need config files for that and provide --command-config flag, for example
